# Intel RAID controller cannot open BIOS and doesn't recognize hard drives

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, intel, raid-controller

I recently bought a second-hand Intel RAID controller (SRCSASLS4I) for my Ubuntu server setup (YunoHost actually).

I connected 3 hard drives that had previously been used for a software RAID (I did not repartition or anything, but I know that the data will most likely be lost).

When my system boots up, this is what happens (stop at 0:50 and ignore my brother gaming):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4MSnUFhCpjnTUd6bGVTcHZjaWc/view?usp=sharing.
After the last black screen, regular boot starts.

I found the error at the end on Google, I'm not sure if the 0.90 version number is the same as on my screen. Apart from a copyright notice, it is the same.

```
Asmedia 106X SATA Controller Ver 0.90 IDE Mode
S.M.A.R.T. Supported
Using PCIE Gen 2
Can't find any device.
```

The table right before this error message contains three ATA entries. I think this might be the 3 hard drives that I connected to the RAID controller, so I think they are detected at some point.

I think this Asmedia SATA Controller is the SATA controller on the RAID controller board. (`lspci | grep asmedia` Prints nothing on the server.)

EDIT: Here is the device page on the Intel website: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/server/srcsasls4i

Comment: I'm not really clear on whether you actually pressed C to configure an array. The controller expects and old array and can't find it, and since you haven't configured a new one yet, there is nothing to boot from? Are you expecting the drives to be in pass-through mode, so Linux can see them? Not all controllers can do that.

Comment: I did press C. And Y afterwards to confirm I want to do configuration. But the config BIOS doesn't load. So no, I don't want the drives to be in pass-through mode, I want to configure the RAID controller.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the Intel RAID controller is rather old and not supported by the motherboard so that it could not load the BIOS.

What I had to do was install MegaRAID Storage Manager on it. Not a trivial task, especially because MSM is only packaged for RHEL and I have an Ubuntu machine.

So if you find yourself in this very edgy case, feel free to ask me how I sovled it, but it's to extensive and a too rare occasion to write it all down here now.